# How to save the user preferences temporarily, until the user logs in into the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Within my rails app, I would like the user to be able to browse and explore without signing in, However, when the user is trying to create a record, it should let him save it only after he/she is signed in. If the user is not signed in, then it should route him to the signup process. The user should not go through the trouble to creating the record all over again.

For example, the user can go to any shopping site, add items to the cart. While checking out, the user is prompted to signup/ sign in. Even if the user is routed to the sign up page, The items are still present in the cart (the user doesn't have to add them agn)

Is there a gem for that? or how can this be achieved in a rails app.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, what you have to do is to create a guest user instance for every user which is not logged in and visits your site. You treat this user as if it was a registered user, persisting everything to the database accordingly. Then when the user comes to the point he has to register you alter his guest user details on the database, this way everything he has done as a guest will remain the same.

You can find a screencast explaining exactly how you can achieve your goal here: [Guest User Record - RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record)

Answer (score 0):

You could store this info in your session, then when the user signs up and logs in to the site , you could show the stored info in the session.